# Dynamic/static loading components/pages/HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I would like to ask your advice on our situation about dynamic/static loading components.

We're developing a "multi language teaching app" for Android/iOS. For UI text we use [ng2-translate plugin](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) (JSON files for each language). For the lesson content we use separate HTML files for each language. In the beginning the user selects a language to learn and then sees related lessons as a list (which comes from a JSON file too). Clicking a lesson loads the related HTML file and dynamically compiles directives/pipes in it (which makes it more interactive). By directives, I mean simple functions like showing a toast when user clicks a custom directive, like this: `<example tooltip="explanation to show as a toast">An example sentence</example>`. But maybe we can use more complex directives in the future.

Up to building the app, everything goes well in browser. But the AoT compiler [does not support](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-properly-dynamically-load-components-into-pages/49519/9?u=emre3) **"dynamic loader components"** in mobile devices, so we need to decide whether or not use this approach. And at that point I'm really confused. We may change our structure but I don't know which way is better.

As far as I can see, we have three options (if there are more, please enlighten me):

- Stop using html files and convert each of them into a component with html templates (using AoT compiler (`--prod` mode)):

  - Be able to use directives/pipes
  - Gain interactivity
  - Gain performance (that's the main purpose of AoT, right? but what if I use hundreds of html pages/components? isn't it a bulky solution?)
  - Use hundreds of **pre-compiled** html pages for grammar lessons, stories, texts...
- Load pure HTML files into an `innerHTML` of a loader component (using AoT compiler (`--prod` mode)):

  - Don't use directives/pipes
  - **Loose interactivity** (except being able to use simple HTML tags like p, strong, em, table etc. --if we count this as an interactive content)
  - Gain performance a bit (as we use AoT?)
- Load HTML files **dynamically as components** via one dynamic template component (using JiT compiler (`--dev` mode)):

  - Be able to use directives/pipes
  - Use separate html files
  - Gain interactivity
  - Loose performance
  - Do something that Angular generally **does not recommend**

I can't decide what to do now, if I want more interactivity, I should drop the performance that Angular proposes.

I just wanted to be able to handle these grammar lessons in a simple syntax (like HTML) as seperate files and not to use/declare components for each of them...

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked same question to Ionic forum and I decided to implement [the solution of a user](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/asking-your-advise-about-dynamic-static-loading-components-pages-html/73980/2?u=emre3) that replied to me:

> I went through this with [Markdown](http://commonmark.org/), tried a bunch of things, and here's what I eventually settled on:
>
> - Store your objects however is convenient for you. In my case, that's markdown source.
> - Define two components; we'll call them `skeleton` and `bone` for now.
> - `skeleton` has an input property giving it the source. In `ngOnChanges`, you need to parse that source into an array of elements, each corresponding to a different type of bone.
> - `skeleton`'s template looks something like this:

```
<template ngFor let-bone [ngForOf]="bones">
  <app-bone [bone]="bone"></app-bone>
</template>
```

> - Make sure each bone has a discriminator indicating its type, and then the BoneComponent template is a big giant switch:

```
<blockquote *ngIf="bone.tag === 'blockquote'">
  <app-bone *ngFor="let child of bone.children" [bone]="child"></app-bone>
</blockquote>

<br *ngIf="bone.tag === 'br'">

... every other block-level element we support...
```

> Note that this can work recursively if you need it to, in that the
> inside of the blockquote case is effectively another skeleton. I'm
> using HTML elements here, but the general technique works equally well
> for other user-defined components (as types of bones).